# Property 'firestore' does not exist on type 'Firebase'

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

**I'm trying to get the exact time a document is created.**

For this I'm using the following imports

```
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase/ngx';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

And the constructor I have is the following.

```
constructor(private aF: AngularFireStore, private firebase: Firebase, private cS: CartService, private ui: UiService){}
```

Here is the method I'm trying to add the Timestamp.

```
    checkout2() {
    const pickup = this.pickup;
    const deliveryname = this.deliveryname;
    const location = this.location;
    const note = this.note;
    const deliverystate = this.deliverystate;
    const cart = this.cS.getCart();
    const total = this.getTotal();
    const uid = this.aS.getInfo();
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.aF.collection('/ordenes').add({
        cart,
          pickup,
          location,
          deliveryname,
          createdAt: this.firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
          note,
          total,
          deliverystate,
          uid
      })
      .then(
        (res) => {
          resolve(res);
          this.cS.cleanCart();
          this.cS.cleanItemCount();
          this.close();

        },
        err => reject(err)
      );
    });
  }
```

I get an error which says:

> Property 'firestore' does not exist on type 'Firebase'

I don't know if I'm importing the wrong library, thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the following package `@ionic-native/firebase/ngx` which does not contain anything related to `firestore`. You can find the api of the package in the following link:

https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/API.md

You need to initialize `firestore`, then you can use the above method, check here for more information:

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-mobile-web#set_up_your_development_environment

Answer (score 0):

This is my initializatin of firebase and firestore with typescript

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { initializeFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'
import config from "./config";

const fb = initializeApp(config.firebaseConfig);
const db = initializeFirestore(fb, {})

export default fb;
```